# Why does my X-box have 200 GB of storage?

Tags: xbox-360

Is this a glitch or something? I was wondering because I don't want to run out without knowing and then have to delete save files.

Comment: remember that alot of time the capacity printed on the box isn't an accurate number, when you see 320GB printed on the box of a harddrive what you actually get is close to 300GB because they count every GB as 1000 MB and not 1024 MB (a pet hate of mine), however 200GB seems weird, is this the maximum capacity or is it how much free space is left

Comment: should also point out 200GB is quite large if your not installing every single game, i haven't played too many 360 games but my PS3 has a 320GB Harddrive and i have over 50 games (Physical and downloaded) + DLC + Multiple PS1 and PS2 Memory Cards + 100 MB worth of Images + an 8GB Backup of my Vita + PSP Games i have yet to copy over and i'm around 70 GB used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, 200GB+ is not even the highest capacity HDD an Xbox 360 can ship with - 250GB and 320GB models are common.

Comment: Thanks, I was just weirded out that they would give you 200gb for the price of a regular xbox.